# Run program from task scheduler when user is not logged on

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

The problem applies to Windows 2012 Server.

I have a commandline application that should be running on a server all the time. The server may be restarted from time to time, and I have only remote access to it. I have created a task in Task Scheduler so to start this application at system startup. There are two ways of starting app in a scheduler:

1. Run when user is logged on - this does not work for me, since if the server is restarted, the task will not run until I log on.
2. Run whether user is logged on or not - in this way, the application is started as a background process and when I log in, I can't see the terminal and observe the status information, which the application prints.

I would like that the application is started right after system restart, and when I log in, I am able to observe the terminal.

Comment: Is the user you log in as a local admin on this machine? I have an idea but it may consist of running this task whether user is logged on or not so it runs then, but if a user logs on, then that name of the task or it's PID is killed, and then it'd start a new process. If that may work, let me know and I'll test to see if I can get something to work this way when no one is logged on this would ensure it runs and if someone does logon, the old process is killed and then a new process starts showing the command window, etc. It may be possible; not sure yet though.